# jquery datatable how to order column date using moment.min.js

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I work with datatable and I want to order a table by a column date.

I loaded moment.min.js and  datetime-moment.js.

My javascript code is

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YY');

order : [ 0, "desc" ]
```

0 is the index of date column

My dates don't order well. The result is

```
31/10/2018
30/11/2018
30/10/2018
29/11/2018
```

I want to order

```
01/10/2018
02/10/2018
03/10/2018
```

How do I have to use moment.min.js and datetime-moment.js to order dates in descending order?

Comment: What do you mean my **one initialization for all application's datatable**? Is it only in some datatables you want to format date?

Comment: I have only one  initialization for all datatables of my application in a javascript

Comment: Why can't you try @mucahid answer?  Even if you have only one initialization for datatables, data schema is always going to be same. How does it matter if you have **one initialization for all datatables**?

Comment: I get a error message You can't redefine a datatable after initilization

Comment: Try show exactly how you initialize the datatables.

Answer (score 0):

Simply render the date column in this way:

```
"columns": [
        ...,
        {
            data: "date",
            render: function (d) {
                return "<span style=\"display:none\">" + moment(d).format("YYYYMMDD") + "</span>" + moment(d).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
            }
        },
        ...]
```

In this way your column will be ordered by YYYYMMDD.